# Why can't I get an imageview out of a gridview by position in android?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I'm trying to retrieve an imageview based on it's position in a grid view.

E.g:

```
int lastvisibleposition = gridView.getLastVisiblePosition();
    int firstvisibleposition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

That gives me two positions, (e.g. 0, 1)

I assumed that I could then:

```
gridView.getItemAtPosition(lastvisibleposition)
```

[getItemAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) "Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list."

So I assumed that I could cast this to an ImageView.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.getItemAtPosition(lastvisibleposition);
```

But imageView is null. I do not understand how I can figure out what the gridview is returning, and/or how to arrive at the imageview so I can continue.

How can I get the actual image views? I'm doing all this so I can have a button at the bottom of the screen cause actions on the 'most' on screen item - it's a vertical scrolling gallery, so if I can return both image views, I can compare how much of each image view is actually on the screen (using imageView.getLocationOnScreen(...)) and cause actions on the image the user wants.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the code that you use to populate the imageviews into the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would check the type of the object that is getting returned before converting it to an ImageView, before this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.getItemAtPosition(lastvisibleposition);
```

Try adding this code :

```
Object temp = gridView.getItemAtPosition(lastvisibleposition);
```

Debug and check the type of temp to ensure that it can be converted to an imageview.

Comment: Checking what type of object was returned by getItemAtPosition set me on the way to solving this problem so thanks a lot.

Comment: I also want to get the imageView , and my `getItemAtPosition` is returning the position(Integer) that I've clicked please can you tell me the right solution..